# install python-csv on a linux machine

Tags: linux, python

i am on MX-linux version 19.1 and i have installed python 3.7.xy

i have also pip installed  - but i do not know how to install the csv package

i tried out many comands

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip 
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
sudo apt-get install python3-csv
sudo apt-get install python-csv
pip install python-csv
```

and

```
python -m pip install csv
```

i used the install-manual

https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

but see what i get

```
Collecting python-csv
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/dc/7d044beccf6d10748ff5ad005441897e84265dea9aea9b39885758cc47fc/python-csv-0.0.11.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named setuptools

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-DachfY/python-csv/
root@mx:/home/martin# ^C
root@mx:/home/martin#
```

can you give me a hint..!?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the following packages and Python modules first:

```
apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev gcc g++

pip install wheel
```

You can then:

```
pip install python-csv
```

If you want to install csv for Python 3, then you'll need to install `python3-setuptools` and `python3-dev` and then `pip3 install csv`.

Comment: @pope You are welcome. You can accept the answer so that it can help others as well.